# Fiz uma funcao pra pegar os valores atuais do array e adicionar em outro, e agora preciso que ao clicar ele puxe apenas o item em especifico q clicou

Tags: angular

```
component:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-trending',
  templateUrl: './trending.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./trending.component.scss']
})
export class TrendingComponent implements OnInit {
  searchText;
  total;
  tradings = [
    {  name: 'Homem Aranha', 
    img: 'https://t.ctcdn.com.br/Zqt5BCp1NYI-loyhw_uFEPyDXC0=/0x496:1198x1171/1198x674/smart/filters:format(webp)/i530736.jpeg',
    
    
    },
    {  name: 'Sherk', 
    img: 'https://static.quizur.com/i/b/55734407898017.8823642455734407568274.35031959.jpg',
    
    },
    {  name: 'Sherk 2', img: 'https://w0.peakpx.com/wallpaper/583/999/HD-wallpaper-shrek-shrek-2.jpg', },
    {  name: 'Sherk 3', img: 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/S/pv-target-images/02616a69d61b80401dc6ed8e35bd2ea9b16d81dd9f3c8b6f32d239a518d0b88d._UY500_UX667_RI_V_TTW_.jpg', }
  ];
  favorites = [];
  favorites2;
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    
  ) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    
    }
    calcularTotal(){
    
    for(var i=0;this.tradings.length > i;i++){
      let teste = this.tradings[i]
      
      this.favorites.push(teste)
      /* this.favorites.indexOf(teste) */
      console.log(this.favorites)
    }
    }
  
}

HTML: 

<section class="search-header">
    <div class="container">
        <div>
            <div class="search-movie" >
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="search" [(ngModel)]="searchText" autocomplete="off"
                    placeholder="Search for movies or TV series" >
            </div>
        </div>    
            <div >
                <h1 style="color: white">Trending</h1>
            <table >
                <tbody class="img-movies" >
                    <tr *ngFor="let trading of tradings | filter:searchText; let i = index" >
                        
                        <!-- <h1>{{movie.name}}</h1> -->
                        <img src="{{trading.img}}" id="imagem-teste" (click)="calcularTotal()" id="teste">
                        <!-- <h1>{{i}}</h1> -->
                       
                    </tr>
                    <!-- <button (click)="separar()">Toggle checkboxes</button> -->
                    <tr *ngFor="let favorite of favorites; let i = index" >
                        <img src="{{favorite.img}}" id="imagem-teste">
                        <h1>{{i}}</h1>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
    </div>
</section>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Para adicionar num array podemos usar o método ***push***, para simplificar um pouco criei uma classe de filmes que contém as propriedades de filme e de url:

```
export class Filmes {
    public name: string
    public img: string
}
```

Dai mudamos a tipagem do seu array para o tipo de ***Filmes***:

```
  searchText: string = "";
  total;
  tradings: Array<Filmes> = [
    {
      name: 'Homem Aranha',
      img: 'https://t.ctcdn.com.br/Zqt5BCp1NYI-loyhw_uFEPyDXC0=/0x496:1198x1171/1198x674/smart/filters:format(webp)/i530736.jpeg',


    },
    {
      name: 'Sherk',
      img: 'https://static.quizur.com/i/b/55734407898017.8823642455734407568274.35031959.jpg',

    },
    { name: 'Sherk 2', img: 'https://w0.peakpx.com/wallpaper/583/999/HD-wallpaper-shrek-shrek-2.jpg', },
    { name: 'Sherk 3', img: 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/S/pv-target-images/02616a69d61b80401dc6ed8e35bd2ea9b16d81dd9f3c8b6f32d239a518d0b88d._UY500_UX667_RI_V_TTW_.jpg', }
  ];
  favorites: Array<Filmes> = [];
  favorites2;
```

Dai criamos os métodos de adicionar favoritos:

```
  adicionarFavorito(index: number)
  {
    this.favorites.push(this.tradings[index]);
  }
```

E por fim chamamos o método dentro do HTML:

```
<section class="search-header">
  <div class="container">
      <div>
          
      </div>    
          <div >
              <h1 style="color: white">Trending</h1>
          <table >
              <tbody class="img-movies" > 
                  <tr *ngFor="let trading of tradings; let i = index" >
                      
                      <!-- <h1>{{movie.name}}</h1> -->
                      <img src="{{trading.img}}" id="imagem-teste" (click)="calcularTotal()" id="teste">
                      <!-- <h1>{{i}}</h1> -->
                      <button (click)="adicionarFavorito(i)">Adicionar aos favoritos</button>
                     
                  </tr>
                  <h1>Meus favoritos: </h1>
                  <tr *ngFor="let favorite of favorites; let i = index" >
                      <img src="{{favorite.img}}" id="imagem-teste">
                      <h1>{{i}}</h1>
                  </tr>
              </tbody>
          </table>
          </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Se quiser dar uma olhadinha sobre criação de classes: https://angular.io/cli/generate

Comment: opa tentei assim, mas nao deu boa, mas fiz de um jeito aq q funfou 
addOnFavorite(item){
      this.tradings.push(item)
    }